# joomla website is displaying a white page

Tags: sql, web, joomla, phpmyadmin

i need to modify a joomla website on my pc, so i downloaded the websitefile via ftp and putted them in the right directory, import the database via cpanel. and i've edited the database name, user, and password in order to couple them.

now the administration panel of the site is working normally.
but the home page and cie are showing a white empty page.

thanks a lot for your help

Comment: there is actually nothing in the logs, except an empty index file, sorry for answering that late.

Answer (score 1):

In your root directory in the configuration.php file make sure `var $live_site = 'http://localhost/yourjoomlainstallroot';`